# Jhipster and ngx-translate stopped to work with upgrade to 0.14

Tags: angular, jhipster, ngx-translate

I'm upgrading an old jhipster angular application from angular 6 to 10.

Jhipster to 0.5.4 to 0.14.0

For the translations I'm using ngx-translate which I'm trying to upgrade as well.

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
```

Since I did the upgrade the translation stopped to work. I checked the webpack.common and the paths seems ok

```
new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
            output: {
                groupBy: [
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/en.json" }
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
            }
        }),
```

my app.module has the import:

```
 TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
```

I'm using shared modules so I imported it as well on the shared.module.ts

Any idea why is not working or how can I do some kind of debug?

Comment: currently ng-jhipster 0.15.0 uses `"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.1",  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",` Any reason why you use different versions of ngx-translate? Also you mentioned version of ng-jhipster but not the version of generator-jhipster, are you trying to upgrade generated code as well?

Comment: I was doing the update manually. Anyway, I ran the jhipster-upgrade to generator version 6.10, the problem is, I have 203 files with conflicts to solve...

Comment: Usually it does not make sense to run jhipster upgrade after few months of development because you have created more value than the value of the initially generated code. While working on the upgrade, you should consider cutting off dependency with ng-jhipster lib and more generally with jhipster generator as you won't generate code anymore with it.